# HTML send Values between two Select Lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Codepen where I need to select an item from first list which sends the selected item to second and vice versa. The issue is I am unable to get the values back to the first list. 
Please help.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQgmbZ?editors=1010

```
<select id="S1" multiple class="form-control form-control-sm" style="height:90px; width:100%; min-width:400px; font-size:8pt; text-align:left;" onchange="SelectValues(this)">
  <option value='AAA'>AAA</option>
  <option value='BBB'>BBB</option>

</select> 
<select id="S2" multiple class="form-control form-control-sm" onclick="DeSelectValues();" style="height:90px; width:400px; min-width:400px; font-size:8pt; text-align:left;"></select>
```

JS:

```
function DeSelectValues() {
  //get the listbox object from id.
  var src = document.getElementById('S2');

  //iterate through each option of the listbox
  for (var count = src.options.length - 1; count >= 0; count--) {
    //if the option is selected, delete the option
    if (src.options[count].selected == true) {
      try {
        src.remove(count, null);
      } catch (error) {
        src.remove(count);
      }
    }
  }


  //var selval = $("#S2 option:selected");
  //var o = new Option(selval, selval);
  //$(o).html($(selval));
  //$("#A1").append(o);


}

function SelectValues(sel) {
    var selval = $("#S1 option:selected");
    var o = new Option(selval, selval);
    $(o).html($(selval));
    $("#S2").append(o);  
}
```

Comment: The logic is identical to your existing `SelectValues()` function, just invert the selectors...? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQgVaO?editors=1010 A bigger problem would be making it work when you select multiple options at once.

Comment: Didn't work. It joins the two values when sending back.

Comment: No, it only does that when you select multiple options at once.

Comment: To move an item from list A to list B you simply append the item to list B (in your SelectValues function).  Why don't you append the item back to list A instead of removing it in Deselect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to move the node from one to the other.

If you just pass a reference to the currently selected `<option>` to the `<select>.append()` method, the node will be moved. There is no need to clone the select element.

```js
function DeSelectValues() {
    var selval = $("#S2 option:selected");
    selval[0].selected = false // deselecting
    $("#S1").append(selval); 
}

function SelectValues(sel) {
    var selval = $("#S1 option:selected");
    selval[0].selected = false // deselecting
    $("#S2").append(selval); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="S1" multiple class="form-control form-control-sm" style="height:90px; width:100%; min-width:400px; font-size:8pt; text-align:left;" onchange="SelectValues(this)">
  <option value='AAA'>AAA</option>
  <option value='BBB'>BBB</option>
  
</select>




<select id="S2" multiple class="form-control form-control-sm" onclick="DeSelectValues();" style="height:90px; width:400px; min-width:400px; font-size:8pt; text-align:left;"></select>
```

Comment: This looks like a very generous contribution. Why did it get a ding?

Comment: Was about to ask the same question. Works too ^^. What more do you want?

Comment: @DomenikReitzner  I didn't downvote it but I would like an explanation of what the problem was ;) Edited the answer to provide a better explanation